# Error checking: like checking for negative numbers, or input that's not a number.

Tags: python-3.x, exception, error-checking

```
weight=input('What is your weight?')
age=input('What is your age?')
w=int(weight)
a=int(weight)
if (a<=10 and w<80):
  print('This person needs to ride the black roller coaster')
if (a<=10 and 80<=w<=200):
  print('This person needs to ride the green roller coaster')
if (a<=10 and w>200):
  print('This person needs to ride the yellow roller coaster')
if (10<a<=20 and w<80):
  print('This person needs to ride the silver roller coaster')
if (10<a<=20 and 80<=w<=200):
  print('This person needs to ride the red roller coaster')
if (10<a<=20 and w>200):
  print('This person needs to ride the purple roller coaster')
else:
  print('This person needs to ride the pink roller coaster')
```

I'm new to this and just don't understand how/where I'm supposed to use "try" and "except" for when the user inputs a number that's negative or a string.

Comment: what result is your ideal?

Comment: Just an error message like 'Entry must be a number greater than 0' if the user input is <=0 or a string

Comment: on what scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `try` like this:

```
def checkValue():
while True:
    try:
        global a, w
        a = int(input("What's your age? ").strip())
        w = int(input("What's your weight? ").strip())
    except ValueError as e:
        print("This is not a number. Try again.")
        continue
    if a <= 0 and w <= 0:
        print("Enter value lager than 0.")
        continue
    else:
        break
    return a, w

checkValue ()
```